# Image Not Displaying Or Error Containts

Tags: php, mysql, html

how i can display image in my web browser using php from mysql database i have all ready uploaded image in database

for display the image i am writting this code file name is down.php and calling that page through post mathod but there is problem occurring can any budy solve my problem i want to give thanks in advance

output is like this->

#%'%#//33//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Comment: What do you set your Content-Type to in PHP?

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use some code similar to this:

```
$photoid = 1 // Set to the actual id of your photo.

// Query your database
$query = "SELECT * FROM `phototable` WHERE `photoid`='".mysql_real_escape_string($photoid)."';";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

// Quick error check
if (!$result) {
  echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
  echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
}

// Output the image
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); // assuming your photo is jpg
echo $row[photodata];
```